# Azure function app (v4 / node.js) no functions found after zip deployment

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, azure-functions

I have deployed a function app and there are no functions visible:

[image: No functions found]

In Kodu what I can see seems correct (the files are under wwwroot):

[image: function app debugger]

In the app files tab. I can see two folder separators that I'm guessing this could be the problem:

[image: App files]

I have `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` disabled and I'm deploying with:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource-group> -n <app-name> --src ./deploy.zip
```

Comment: What is the Hosting plan of your Azure Function ?

Comment: Pricing plan: Y1 / consumption plan / windows machine

Comment: Even I tried with the same Consumption Plan, Please check the posted Answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying millions of things, this is what did it for me:

My folder structure is the following:

```
dist <-- this folder is present if you use TypeScript
│   └── src
│       ├── dal
│       ├── functions
│       │    └── <MY FUNCTIONS ARE HERE>
│       └── shared
├── host.json
└── package.json
```

One of my changes was in the `host.json`:

```json
  // ...
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.0.0, 5.0.0)" <-- upgraded the version
  }
```

Another thing I did was to upgrade everything (Azure CLI, function core tools, etc.).

And finally, I saw this in the docs:

> During preview, the v4 model requires you to set the app setting *AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags* to *EnableWorkerIndexing*. For more information, see [Enable v4 programming model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-node-upgrade-v4?tabs=azure-cli-set-indexing-flag%2Cv4#enable-v4-programming-model).

To create it I needed to run:

```
az functionapp config appsettings set --name <FUNCTION_APP_NAME> \
--resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> \
--settings AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags=EnableWorkerIndexing
```

Then I restarted the function app and it finally worked.

Comment: I had this same issue and it took way too long to understand this solution... the function v4 dev experience has some significant gaps

Answer (score 1):

I have deployed the `Azure Function` with the given command.

Even Iam unable to see the `Functions` in the Function tab of the deployed `Azure Function`.

> In the app files tab. I can see two folder separators that I'm guessing this could be the problem:

In `App files` only configuration files will be available.

[image]

- To check and run the deployed function, Navigate to the `App Service Editor(Preview)`.

[image]

- Click on `Open Editor`, you can see the deployed Functions.
- Select and Run the Function, `Output` is shown on Right Pane.

[image]

My `package.json` file:

```cs
{
  "name": "nodefunction",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^4.0.0-alpha.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "main": "src/functions/*.js"
}
```

Comment: I can see the functions under `src/functions` do you know if `"main": "dist/src/functions/*.js"` (this value was created by default by the function tools) in the `package.json` could be the problem? My functions don't have the `dist` folder.

Comment: Updated my `package.json` file in the update section of the answer.

Comment: My Functions are under `src/functions` folder itself. Even I don't have dist folder.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the only difference is that my project is a TypeScript project. I cannot remove the dist folder because I need a configuration that will work both locally and in the deployment.

Comment: No matter typescript/javascript, the functions are available in the `App Service Editor`.