No job functions found - Azure function 4.0 with Typescript, gRPC server and client
I have created gRPC server and Azure Function App with Node.js and TypeScript.
The check the following directory structure -
MyGrpcFunctionApp -> src -> functions -> index.ts
//import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";

import { Context } from './custom-types';
import { HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions";
import * as AzureFunctions from "@azure/functions";
import * as grpc from '@grpc/grpc-js';
import * as protoLoader from '@grpc/proto-loader';
import path from 'path';

const PROTO_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'proto', 'helloworld.proto');
const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH);
const protoDescriptor = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);
const helloworld = protoDescriptor.helloworld as any;

const client = new helloworld.Greeter('localhost:50051', grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

/* const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
  client.sayHello({ name: 'Azure' }, (error: any, response: any) => {
    if (error) {
      context.res = { status: 500, body: error.message };
    } else {
      context.res = { status: 200, body: response.message };
    }
  });
}; */

interface HttpResponse {
    status?: number;
    headers?: { [key: string]: string };
    body?: any;
}

interface ExtendedContext extends Context {
    res: HttpResponse;
}



const httpTrigger = async function (context: ExtendedContext, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    context.log('HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    
    let body: any;

    // Log the incoming request method and URL
    context.log(`Request method: ${req.method}`);
    context.log(`Request URL: ${req.url}`);

    // Check if req.body is a ReadableStream and read it
    if (req.body instanceof ReadableStream) {
        const reader = req.body.getReader();
        const decoder = new TextDecoder();
        let result = '';
        let done = false;

        while (!done) {
            const { value, done: streamDone } = await reader.read();
            done = streamDone;
            if (value) {
                result += decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
            }
        }

        try {
            body = JSON.parse(result); // Assuming JSON body
            context.log('Parsed body:');
        } catch (error) {
            context.res = {
                status: 400,
                body: "Invalid JSON body"
            };
            return;
        }
    } else {
        body = req.body; // If body is already parsed as an object
    }

    //const name = req.query.get('name');
    const name = req.query.get('name') || (req.body ? body.name : null);

    if (name) {
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, 
            body: "Hello " + name
        };
    } else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
};

export default httpTrigger;



Also, I have created function.json file -
{
    "bindings": [
      {
        "authLevel": "function",
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "name": "req",
        "methods": ["get", "post"]
      },
      {
        "type": "http",
        "direction": "out",
        "name": "res"
      }
    ],
    "scriptFile": "../dist/src/functions/index.js",
    "entryPoint": "httpTrigger"
  }
  

Did not get any error during deployment. However, after running the func start --verbose I am getting the following statements -
> func start

Debugger attached.

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5907 Commit hash: N/A +807e89766a92b14fd07b9f0bc2bea1d8777ab209 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-08-13T12:25:55.129Z] Debugger attached.
[2024-08-13T12:25:55.248Z] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-08-13T12:26:00.145Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000A77BA962'.

Anyone can solve this issue?
We need to see the function app URL -
http://localhost:7071/api/httpTrigger
This will not showing 404 page

Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75994451/azure-function-app-v4-node-js-no-functions-found-after-zip-deployment

You need to ensure that the function signature is correct. Use my code below to get the expected response.
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions"
import * as grpc from '@grpc/grpc-js';
import * as protoLoader from '@grpc/proto-loader';
import path from 'path';

const PROTO_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'proto', 'helloworld.proto');
const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH);
const protoDescriptor = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);
const helloworld = protoDescriptor.helloworld as any;

const client = new helloworld.Greeter('localhost:7071', grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

interface HttpResponse {
    status?: number;
    headers?: { [key: string]: string };
    body?: any;
}

interface ExtendedContext extends Context {
    res: HttpResponse;
}

const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, req: HttpRequest): Promise<void> {
    context.log('HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    let body: any;

    context.log(`Request method: ${req.method}`);
    context.log(`Request URL: ${req.url}`);

    if (req.body instanceof ReadableStream) {
        const reader = req.body.getReader();
        const decoder = new TextDecoder();
        let result = '';
        let done = false;

        while (!done) {
            const { value, done: streamDone } = await reader.read();
            done = streamDone;
            if (value) {
                result += decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
            }
        }

        try {
            body = JSON.parse(result);
            context.log('Parsed body:');
        } catch (error) {
            context.res = {
                status: 400,
                body: "Invalid JSON body"
            };
            return;
        }
    } else {
        body = req.body;
    }

    //const name = req.query.get('name');
    const name = req.query.name || (req.body ? body.name : null);

    if (name) {
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, 
            body: "Hello " + name
        };
    } else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }

};

export default httpTrigger;

You can see the request URL and the response as well.
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5907 Commit hash: N/A +807e89766a92b14fd07b9f0bc2bea1d8777ab209 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-08-14T05:30:01.015Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        HttpTrigger1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-08-14T05:30:05.952Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000000D2022A4'.
[2024-08-14T05:30:08.431Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=62a683a7-f84a-466f-b6af-09b4c13e9dc3)
[2024-08-14T05:30:08.509Z] Request method: GET
[2024-08-14T05:30:08.509Z] HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-08-14T05:30:08.509Z] Request URL: http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1?name=Afreen
[2024-08-14T05:30:08.569Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=62a683a7-f84a-466f-b6af-09b4c13e9dc3, Duration=154ms)

Update-
You can use the below code for v4 model which uses app, HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext.
import { app, HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from "@azure/functions";
import * as grpc from '@grpc/grpc-js';
import * as protoLoader from '@grpc/proto-loader';
import path from 'path';

const PROTO_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'proto', 'helloworld.proto');
const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH);
const protoDescriptor = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);
const helloworld = protoDescriptor.helloworld as any;

const client = new helloworld.Greeter('localhost:7071', grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

interface HttpResponse {
    status?: number;
    headers?: { [key: string]: string };
    body?: any;
}

interface ExtendedContext extends InvocationContext {
    res: HttpResponse;
}

export async function httpTrigger1(req: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponseInit> {
    context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${req.url}"`);

    let body: any;

    context.log(`Request method: ${req.method}`);
    context.log(`Request URL: ${req.url}`);

    if (req.body instanceof ReadableStream) {
        const reader = req.body.getReader();
        const decoder = new TextDecoder();
        let result = '';
        let done = false;

        while (!done) {
            const { value, done: streamDone } = await reader.read();
            done = streamDone;
            if (value) {
                result += decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
            }
        }

        try {
            body = JSON.parse(result);
            context.log('Parsed body:',body);
        } catch (error) {
            return {
                status: 400,
                body: "Invalid JSON body"
            };
        }
    } else {
        body = req.body;
    }

    const name = req.query.get('name') || (req.body ? body.name : null);

    if (name) {
        return {
            body: "Hello " + name
        };
    } else {
        return {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }
};

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: httpTrigger1
});


Thank you so much for your kind help. However, we are using Azure V4 and there we dont have AzureFunction, Context and context as a node module.
Do you have any solution based on Azure v4?

@WebsiteTests I have used V3 model as in the OP you have mentioned about function.json file. In V4 model there is no function.json file.

If you are talking about Azure function core tool version 4 then I am also using the same version

@WebsiteTests did you get the solution?

As I checked the GRPC server and client both are working properly. We need to use the following line -
import { app, HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from "@azure/functions";
Instead of the
import { AzureFunction, Context, HttpRequest } from "@azure/functions"
I will check and share you the update.

@WebsiteTests Are you using v3 model or v4? there is no function.json file in v4 model but I see you are using function.json file

@WebsiteTests Added code which uses import { app, HttpRequest, HttpResponseInit, InvocationContext } from "@azure/functions";
